# Self-diagnose components in the circuit

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, debugging

How can I tackle self-diagnosis problem within my Arduino project?
For example, I have a temperature sensor and humidity sensor. How can I know if they work or not on Arduino start or inside the sketch loop?

Answer (score 2):

You could get your program to output messages to the serial pin on your board, Tx. For example:

```
Serial.begin(9600) //baud rate of 9600

Serial.print("Debug Message");
```

You can use this to print out string and integers. Here is the link to further information on the Arduino website - https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/serial

If you are already using the Serial pins then you could use the SoftwareSerial Library - https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial

This library allows you to make two other pins on your board Tx and Rx. For example:

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(12,13) //Makes pin 12 Rx and pin 13 Tx

mySerial.begin(9600) //baud rate of 9600

mySerial.println("Debug Message");
```

To read the output from any of the pins on your arduino - use a USB to TTL serial cable. Plug it into your computer and use a program like PuTTY to connect to the serial cable and read the messages coming from the Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

If you can define "it works" in code (e.g. the temperature is between X and Y degrees, and changes no faster than 2 degrees per second), and all you need is a "Yes" or a "No", then you can write this into code, then the easiest way is to use an LED. Make sure you blink it, rather than having it on steadily, so you can tell if it's frozen.

Make sure you try unplugging your sensor, to understand what it does when it fails; this is one thing you specifically want to test for.

If you specifically do not want to do this in your main loop, you can do an interrupt-driven version, but that adds a lot of complexity. I suggest you do it in your main loop if you can.

You can use the current time to blink the light regularly:

```
if (everything_is_working()) {
  if (millis()%10000<1000) {
     <turn led on>
  } else {
     <turn led off>
  }
}
```

The two numbers let you control the flashes. I've used 10,000 and 1,000; this means that out of every 10,000 millis (10 seconds), the led is on 1,000 millis (1 second). Depending on your preference, you can adjust these to your liking. You can also add an else clause which blinks a different pattern depending on what is wrong - 9 seconds on out of 10 for a problem with the humidity sensor, and 5 seconds out of 10 for the temperature sensor having issues.

If your sketch isn't running, the led will stay in it's current state - either on, or off, indefinitely. If your project has no power, the light will obviously be off.

If you want more data, you can either make more complex blink codes - short-long-short-long, for example - or add multiple lights, or even a three-colour LED, with different colours indicating different problems.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be handy if you want to do detailed debugging (like outputting numbers) but your serial port is already in use for something, like a GPS. You can use a second Arduino as a "debugging interface" using SPI or I2C. For example, using SPI:

[image: Debug via SPI]

Or via I2C:

[image: Debug via I2C]

In these examples the "debugging" Uno also supplies power to the "main" Uno via the 5 V / Gnd pins.

I have a description about this method on [Debugging using SPI/I2C and a second processor](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11329). Code is available at: http://gammon.com.au/Arduino/SPI_Debugging.zip and http://gammon.com.au/Arduino/I2C_Debugging.zip .

To demonstrate the idea, on the "main" Uno this is an example of sending debugging info via SPI:

```C++
// make true to debug, false to not
#define DEBUG true

#include <SPI.h>

// conditional debugging
#if DEBUG 

  #define beginDebug()  do { SPI.begin (); SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8); } while (0)
  #define Trace(x)      SPIdebug.print   (x)
  #define Trace2(x,y)   SPIdebug.print   (x,y)
  #define Traceln(x)    SPIdebug.println (x)
  #define Traceln2(x,y) SPIdebug.println (x,y)
  #define TraceFunc()   do { SPIdebug.print (F("In function: ")); SPIdebug.println (__PRETTY_FUNCTION__); } while (0)

  class tSPIdebug : public Print
  {
  public:
    virtual size_t write (const byte c)  
      { 
      digitalWrite(SS, LOW); 
      SPI.transfer (c); 
      digitalWrite(SS, HIGH); 
      return 1;
      }  // end of tSPIdebug::write
  }; // end of tSPIdebug

  // an instance of the SPIdebug object
  tSPIdebug SPIdebug;

#else
  #define beginDebug()  ((void) 0)
  #define Trace(x)      ((void) 0)
  #define Trace2(x,y)   ((void) 0)
  #define Traceln(x)    ((void) 0)
  #define Traceln2(x,y) ((void) 0)
  #define TraceFunc()   ((void) 0)
#endif // DEBUG


long counter;
unsigned long start;

void setup() {
  start = micros ();

  beginDebug ();
  Traceln (F("Commenced device-under-test debugging!"));
  TraceFunc ();  // show current function name

}  // end of setup

void foo ()
  {
  TraceFunc (); // show current function name
  }

void loop() 
{

  counter++;
  if (counter == 100000)
  {
    Traceln (F("100000 reached."));
    Trace (F("took "));
    Traceln (micros () - start);
    counter = 0;
    foo ();
  }  // end of if

}  // end of loop
```

If DEBUG is true then the debugging prints are activated. Otherwise they turn into "no code".

The receiving end looks like this:

```C++
volatile char buf [1000];
volatile int inpoint, outpoint;

void setup (void)
{
  Serial.begin (115200);   // debugging

  Serial.println ();
  Serial.println (F("Commencing debugging session ..."));
  Serial.println ();

  // have to send on master in, *slave out*
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);

  // turn on SPI in slave mode
  SPCR |= bit (SPE);

  // now turn on interrupts
  SPCR |= bit (SPIE);

}  // end of setup


// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
byte c = SPDR;  // grab byte from SPI Data Register
int next = inpoint + 1;  // next insert point

  // wrap-around at end of buffer
  if (next >= sizeof buf)
    next = 0;

  if (next == outpoint)  // caught up with removal point?
    return;  // give up

  // insert at insertion point
  buf [inpoint] = c;
  inpoint = next;  // advance to next

}  // end of interrupt routine SPI_STC_vect

void loop (void)
{
  // insertion and removal point the same, nothing there
  noInterrupts ();  // atomic test of a 16-bit variable
  if (outpoint == inpoint)
    {
    interrupts ();
    return;
    }
  interrupts ();

  // display anything found in the circular buffer
  Serial.print (buf [outpoint]);

  noInterrupts ();
  if (++outpoint >= sizeof buf)
    outpoint = 0;  // wrap around
  interrupts ();

}  // end of loop
```

There is a 1000 byte buffer which will cope with bursts of incoming data, which is then sent out the serial port on the debugging Uno (that is, to your serial monitor).

The linked library above includes code for SPI and I2C debugging interfaces.

---

Having said that, the simplest thing is just to do serial debugging prints inside your code on the main device, if that is practical.

Remember to use the `F()` macro, or your debugging code might take up so much RAM it causes a crash.

eg.

```C++
Serial.println (F("Temperature sensor working."));
```